# Graphics card vs. motherboard compatibility

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I have an MSI FM2-A55M-E33 motherboard (also an AMD Athlon x4 750k quad core processor,
4GB RAM, and 520W power supply).  Is an Asus AMD Radeon R9 270X OC DirectCU II graphics card compatible?

Comment: Welcome.  Questions about shopping for hardware (or software) are specifically excluded on the site.  I edited you question to remove at least the overt request for shopping assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided it will physically fit in your PC case it will work fine.
(This fairly mid to high-end range graphics card is pretty overkill for your 2-3 years mid-range PC though. You won't be able to get full performance out of it with this CPU/motherboard.)

By the looks of it your power-supply at 500 W should be able to handle it, as long as you are not attaching more than 3-4 hard-drives to the system.

Nevertheless: Check it !
Add the maximum power-draw of the motherboard, graphics-card, harddrives and any other stuff that is powered by the computer (like USB stuff) together.
Compare that against your power-supply. Ideally you should not draw more than 80-85% of the rated capacity of the power-supply.

Answer (score 0):

What is the confusion?

Your [mobo](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/FM2-A55M-E33.html#hero-specification) supports PCIe v2 and the [gfx card](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/R9270XDC22GD5/specifications/) supports PCIe v3 and below, therefore they are compatible.

Your more pressing consideration are whether the card will physically fit in your case, and whether your PSU can kick out enough power to feed it. In both case, read the component specifications for each, and work it out.